# Validation Attribute - checking a dynamic number of fields on a form ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I have a number of forms with checkboxes that need validating. For example I might have a form with 3 checkboxes and one of those 3 needs ticking and another form with 50 boxes that might need at least one item checking.

Does anyone have a ValidationAttribute that would work under these circumstances.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with class-level validation attributes (as opposed to property-level attributes). I've written a blog [article](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-3-how-to-cover-all-your-client-side-form-validation-needs-without-writing-any-javascript-part1/) describing how to implement this on both the server and the client side if you want to make this really ajaxy... :-)